# How to register Drum.UriMaker<> using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, simple-injector

I'm using [Drum](https://github.com/pmhsfelix/drum) which provides a generic class `UriMaker:

```
public class UriMaker<TController>
{
    // I need use this one
    public UriMaker(UriMakerContext context, HttpRequestMessage request) { }

    public UriMaker(Func<MethodInfo, RouteEntry> mapper, UrlHelper urlHelper) { }
}
```

Used like this:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public UserController(UriMaker<UserController> urlMaker) {}
}
```

I've used to register it with Unity:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(UriMaker<>),
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(UriMakerContext), typeof(HttpRequestMessage)));
```

but now migrating to Simple Injector. I already have this:

```
UriMakerContext uriMaker = config.MapHttpAttributeRoutesAndUseUriMaker();
container.RegisterSingle(uriMakerContext);
```

So how now register `UriMaker<>` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is possible to configure Simple Injector to allow injecting an `UriMaker<TController>` directly into your controllers, I strongly advice against this for multiple reasons.

First of all, you should strive to minimize the dependencies your application takes on external libraries. This can easily be done by defining an application specific abstraction (conforming the [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)).

Second, injecting the `UriMaker` directly makes your extremely hard to test, since the `UriMaker` is pulled into your test code, while it assumes an active HTTP request and assumes the Web API route system to be configured correctly. These are all things you don't want your test code to be dependent upon.

Last, it makes [verifying the object graph](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration) harder, since the UriMaker depends on an `HttpRequestMessage`, which is a runtime value. In general, runtime values should not be injected into the constructors of your services. You should build up your object graph with components (the stuff that contains the application's behavior) and you send runtime data through the object graph after construction.

So instead, I suggest the following abstraction:

```
public interface IUrlProvider
{
    Uri UriFor<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action);
}
```

Now your controllers can depend on this `IUrlProvider` instead of depending on an external library:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUrlProvider urlProvider;

    public UserController(IUrlProvider urlProvider)
    {
        this.urlProvider = urlProvider;
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        this.urlProvider.UriFor<HomeController>(c => c.SomeFancyAction());
    }
}
```

Under the covers you of course still need to call `Drum`, and for this you need to define a proxy implementation for `IUrlProvider`:

```
public class DrumUrlProvider : IUrlProvider
{
    private readonly UriMakerContext context;
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage> messageProvider;

    public DrumUrlProvider(UriMakerContext context,
        Func<HttpRequestMessage> messageProvider)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.messageProvider= messageProvider;
    }

    public Uri UriFor<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage message = this.messageProvider.Invoke();
        var maker = new UriMaker<TController>(this.context, message);
        return maker.UriFor(action);
    }
}
```

This implementation can be registered as singleton in the following way:

```
container.EnableHttpRequestMessageTracking(config);

UriMakerContext uriMakerContext =
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutesAndUseUriMaker();

IUrlProvider drumProvider = new DrumUrlProvider(uriMakerContext, 
    () => container.GetCurrentHttpRequestMessage());

container.RegisterSingle<IUrlProvider>(drumProvider);
```

This example uses the [Simple Injector Web API integration package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi/) to allow retrieving the current request's `HttpRequestMessage` using the `EnableHttpRequestMessageTracking` and `GetCurrentHttpRequestMessage` extension methods as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#getting-the-current-request-s-httprequestmessage).

Comment: This is just brilliant, thank you! Meanwhile I found this solution: http://pastebin.com/LhidzEVF. I like your more because it involves less new classes at least. And helps to avoid injecting external component directly.

Comment: @abatishchev: Yep, your solution is the solution I discourage in my answer on line one :-)